# Publishing an Outlook Add-In to the Office Store. What files do I need to send to Microsoft for approval?

Tags: office-store

The team I work with is looking to introduce a new Add-In for Outlook.

This is our first case of doing this and I couldn't find any information about exactly what files we need to send to Microsoft for approval?

For example our code will be making use of an external web API to interact with our online application.  Will we need to provide the code for the external web API?

EDIT:  To provide a bit more detail.  I'd imagine that I'd need to submit the manifest file.  Would I also need to submit:

- html/Javascript files hosted on our server that are used by the
  Add-In.
- Code from an external Web API that the Add-In makes use of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let people know in case anyone needs to answer the same problem.

It looks like from a coding perspective only the manifest file is needed to submit for approval.  So there is no need to send any server side code as part of the submission.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation explaining what is needed to submit an app or add-in to AppSource is available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/store/use-the-seller-dashboard-to-submit-to-the-office-store)

For Outlook add-ins, you should include the manifest file and complete the required metadata fields.